# Ignore android generated files fro, GIT

Tags: java, android, git

I am working on some android (on windows OS) project and I don't want to submit the generated files. I created `.gitignore` file in my root dir with notepad and added to it this lines:

```
Shale/bin/classes/com/shale/activities/
Shale/gen/com/shale/activities/
```

but when I am running in the cmd `git status` I see this:
[image]

What should I do for make git ignore this?

I know that git reading the `.gitignore` file, because I have create a text file `test.txt` and added it to the .`gitignore` and git ignored it.

Thanks

Comment: When did you added them to the .gitignore?
After they were created already?

Comment: Yes, I think I did add them before creating the .gitignore

Comment: you can also add .gitignore inside each folder.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854019/ignore-android-generated-files-fro-git#comment26065129_17854019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've committed the files before adding them to .gitignore. Try to remove them with the command (it won't delete your files):

```
git rm --cached <your-files>
```

Commit your changes, and from now on, git should ignore any changes to your files.

Additionally you can also check out the [example .gitignore for android projects](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).

Comment: Should I then make a commit and push?

Comment: Yes, you should. When you say `git status` it should tell you that you've deleted the files (even if they still exist on drive).

Answer (score 1):

In the root directory of your project add a `.gitignore` file with the following contents

```
bin/
gen/
```

That should ignore those directory.

From the screen shot you have attached it seems that you have already added those directories and its content to the git repository. So you will have to delete it from the index using following command

```
git rm --cached bin/
git rm --cached gen/
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html

Answer (score 1):

you can also have .gitignore inside folder to ignore specified folder content.